# I can upload images from gallery but not from camera in Android Studio

Tags: android, file-upload, android-camera

I am trying to finish my app, and the only thing I have left is getting the camera to work in Android. I have the images uploading from the gallery, and it is working perfectly. However, I do not know how to add the code to get the camera to work. Here is my MainActivity.java file:

```
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;
    public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    public String url ="https://mywebsite.com";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings();
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new xWebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {
            // For 3.0+ Devices (Start)
            // onActivityResult attached before constructor
            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType)
            {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }
            // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
            {
                if (uploadMessage != null) {
                    uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                    uploadMessage = null;
                }
                uploadMessage = filePathCallback;

                Intent intent = null;
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
                }
                try
                {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                {
                    uploadMessage = null;
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            //For Android 4.1 only
            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture)
            {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }
            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg)
            {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE) {
                if (uploadMessage == null)
                    return;
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent));
                uploadMessage = null;
            }
        } else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == mUploadMessage)
                return;
            // Use MainActivity.RESULT_OK if you're implementing WebView inside Fragment
            // Use RESULT_OK only if you're implementing WebView inside an Activity
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != MainActivity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
    private class xWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

I have already set permissions in the manifest file as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

I have spent almost an entire week trying to figure this out. At this point, I am absolutely clueless. If someone could help me by telling me the code to add, and where to add it, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: There is nothing with camera or a camera intent in your code. Using a camera intent is pretty basic and examples how to take a picture are all over the place.

Comment: Further: You should tell when the camera app should be called. Show your html source which tells the user a picture can be taken. Start your post with that code.

Comment: I figured it out. From the numerous searches, I discover, to no surprise, that I'm not the only one who has been struggling with this. Therefore, I found the answer on https://github.com/mgks/Os-FileUp . This fixed everything. If you're struggling with this, I hope this helps you.